Why does SQL Server assume that a double nested owned entity is not null?
Description

Essentially what I am trying to do is to have a result (here called Foo) with some details (here called Bar)

The details are optional (e.g. an error could occur)
The details contain a bunch of things, including another entity (here called Baz).
Bar is not required but when set Baz must be set as well.
The Baz type is used because the Baz type is reused in several times.


When trying to load an item from the database, it incorrectly assumes that the Baz entity is not null even though the Bar entity is null (and thus Baz should be null as well.)

At least that's my current understanding of the issue.


This issue is SQL Server specific and doesn't occur with the in-memory database.

Question: Why does this cause issues and how can specify this relation correctly?
Question: Is there some sort of workaround to get this working?
Exception
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred while reading a database value for property 'BazDto.BarDtoFooDtoId'. The expected type was 'System.Guid' but the actual value was null.
 ---> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.ThrowIfNull()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Guid()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetGuid(Int32 i)
   at lambda_method32(Closure, QueryContext, DbDataReader, ResultContext, SingleQueryResultCoordinator)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at lambda_method32(Closure, QueryContext, DbDataReader, ResultContext, SingleQueryResultCoordinator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\paul\CODE\playground\Playground_02\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 88
   at Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\paul\CODE\playground\Playground_02\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 88
   at Program.<Main>(String[] args)

Reproducible Example
// 1. Create a ConsoleApp project with .NET 8
// 2. Add The package references into the '.csproj'
// 3. Replace 'Program.cs' with this code
// 4. Update the ConnectionString to point to an SqlServer instance
// 5. Generate database migrations.
// 6. Run to reproduce the issue

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public class FooDto
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public BarDto? Bar { get; set; }
}

[Owned]
public class BarDto
{
    public BazDto Baz { get; set; } = null!;

    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/breaking-changes#nested-optional-dependents-sharing-a-table-and-with-no-required-properties-are-disallowed
    public int _RequiredFieldToAvoidWarning { get; set; }
}

[Owned]
public class BazDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ExampleContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<FooDto> Foos { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(options);

        options.EnableDetailedErrors();

        options.UseLoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
        {
            builder.AddConsole();
            builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
        }));

        var connectionString = @"CONNECTION_STRING"; // UPDATE
        options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<FooDto>(fooBuilder =>
        {
            fooBuilder.OwnsOne(x => x.Bar, barBuilder =>
            {
                barBuilder
                    .OwnsOne(x => x.Baz, bazBuilder =>
                    {
                        // This is required for the issue to occur, there needs to be a separate table
                        bazBuilder.ToTable("Baz");
                    });
            });
        });
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await using var context = new ExampleContext();

        await context.Database.MigrateAsync();
        
        context.Foos.Add(new FooDto()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Bar = null,
        });
        
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();

        // This will throw an exception
        var result = await context.Foos
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Include(x => x.Bar)
            .ThenInclude(x => x!.Baz)
            .FirstAsync();
    }
}

<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.10" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="8.0.10" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.10" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="8.0.10">
<PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="8.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="8.0.1" />

The generated database migrations are too large to be included in the question and can be found here:

Migrations/20241016062147_Initial.cs
Migrations/20241016062147_Initial.Designer.cs
Migrations/ExampleContextModelSnapshot.cs

Logs
Originally, I tried to include the logs in the question but they exceed the maximum size.
The logs can be found here.

I'm not sure why you've shown us quite so much code, surely the problem is in Foo? Can you show the schema for the Foo table?

Apparently it's not a supported setup. Just use a regular 1:1 relationship between Bar and Baz.

Bar is going to need a null-able int? BazId to serve as the PrincipalKey for the relationship between Bar and Baz if Baz's are stored in a separate table. Foo and Bar will reside in the Foo table by default under the owned relationship. This is either missing from your example or you are missing this configuration.

@iakobski The example is complete and should reproduce the issue on it's own. If you create a console app and provide a connection string for an SqlServer instance it should reproduce the issue. There is nothing else configured for the FooDto entity.

@GertArnold Not sure if I understand you correctly but this is the case. It's a 1:1:1 relationship. However the intermediate object BarDto is optional and this should make the last BazDto optional as well, but somehow that doesn't happen.

@user272507 I'm asking what does the table look like? We can't reproduce this as we don't know your database schema.

@StevePy I don't understand what you mean, where would this BazId go? The provided example is complete and runnable standalone, there is nothing missing.

@iakobski Now I understand what your asking. I've simply used the builtin database migrations to create the table. I will add the generated files to the question.

Your migrations file (first file) is missing Bar, and the foreign key is on Baz to Foo - are you sure that's the right file?

@iakobski I've double checked, it's the right file. It doesn't really surprise me that Bar is missing it was merged into the Foo entity because it's an owned entity in a 1:1 relationship. It does seem to have this Baz.BarDtoFooDtoId field that is a foreign key to Foo.Id. That should work in theory but somehow it seems to get confused.

A 1-to-1 owned entity relationship with same-table (foo-bar) will use the PK of the owner as the PK of the owned. If you want Baz to be in a 1-to-1 owned relationship with Bar but using a separate table, Either Baz needs a BarId (FooId) GUID as FK or Bar needs an int BazId to serve as the PrincipalKey for the relationship. Otherwise with a same-table, Baz would be appended to Foo as null-able columns.

@StevePy EF automatically created a column named BarDtoFooDtoId that should serve this purpose. In my opinion the database tables seem fine but the generated query for retrieval is incorrect.

The query isn't incorrect. The code is. It explicitly states that Baz is required. Since EF Core 7, returning a null for a nullable type results in an error. This is thoroughly documented and the question's code silences the warnings with BazDto Baz { get; set; } = null!;.

Diagnosis
This appears to be an undocumented breaking change from EF6 to EF7 or simply a bug.
I've tried using different versions of the packages with the following results:

Version 8.0.10 -> issue occurs
Version 7.0.20 -> issue occurs
Version 6.0.3 -> no problem

This is the SQL query generated for version 6.0.3:
SELECT TOP(2) [f].[Id], [f].[Bar__RequiredFieldToAvoidWarning], [b].[BarDtoFooDtoId], [b].[Id]
FROM [Foos] AS [f]
LEFT JOIN [Baz] AS [b] ON CASE
    WHEN [f].[Bar__RequiredFieldToAvoidWarning] IS NOT NULL THEN [f].[Id]
END = [b].[BarDtoFooDtoId]
WHERE [f].[Id] = @__fooId_0

This is the query generated with version 7.0.20:
SELECT TOP(2) [f].[Id], [f].[Bar__RequiredFieldToAvoidWarning], [b].[BarDtoFooDtoId], [b].[Id]
FROM [Foos] AS [f]
LEFT JOIN [Baz] AS [b] ON [f].[Id] = [b].[BarDtoFooDtoId]
WHERE [f].[Id] = @__fooId_0

Both of these queries return the exact same result, but this suggests that the logic for the generation was changed.
My interpretation is that they did some sort of refactoring and introduced a bug.
Workaround

I was able to resolve this issue by making BarDto.Baz optional:
[Owned]
public class BarDto
{
    // Make this optional
    public BazDto? Baz { get; set; } = null!;

    public int _RequiredFieldToAvoidWarning { get; set; }
}


In my opinion, this change should not be necessary and if intentional this should have been documented as breaking change.
That seems to make the issue disappear but it seems to be very inconsistent.
There were other locations which were extremely similar where the issue didn't occur.
That's one of the first things that I tried and I remember that it didn't work.
I suspect, that I forgot to regenerate the migrations after making this change.
I am just happy that it works now.


The bug is in the code. public BazDto Baz { get; set; } = null!; tells EF that Baz is NOT nullable. It was already announced before EF Core 7 was released that nullable types would be taken into account. It is documented

Enforcing required owned types started EF Core 6: Nested optional dependents sharing a table and with no required properties are disallowed

@PanagiotisKanavos But the parent entity is clearly optional: public BarDto? Bar { get; set; }. I would assume that if the parent entity is null, that it would understand that the child entity is also null but it incorrectly assumes that it's not null. The documentation simply doesn't mention it and it silently changed from EF6 to EF7. (I don't think the linked breaking change explains this because BarDto._RequiredFieldToAvoidWarning is required and therefore that shouldn't apply.)

Think what you're asking. You're asking for those objects to be mapped to the same table, same row as the parent. You're asking that a set of those columns is nullable but a subset for that set isn't nullable. How is this going to be represented in the database? It's impossible. ORMs don't change how the database works, they only Map the relational constructs to application objects.

I'd argue that the previous behavior was the real bug because it allowed unrepresentable types. You could end up with filled Baz columns even though the Bar columns were null. How would you load row? What would the Foo object look like? I suspect this was allowed due to timing constraints or because NRTs weren't fully enforced yet

@PanagiotisKanavos I think I understand what you mean. I thought it was "smart enough" to figure things out for me, but I guess I need to think more in terms of the database representation. Thank you!
